# EasyMock Handling of Multiple Exceptions in one method

Tags: java, easymock

In my code I expceted one BusinessServiceException.And in the Catch block of this BusinesserviceException it throws another RestValidationException.I am not able to handle this RestValidation Exception.The error I got is unexpected RestValidationException.
Please Help...

```
try {
        if(null == identityProxy.getIdentityProxy() || null == identityProxy.getIdentityProxyType() || identityProxy.getIdentityProxy().isEmpty() || identityProxy.getIdentityProxyType().isEmpty()){
            throw new RestValidationException(RestErrorCodes.INVALID_IDENTITY_PROXY.toString());
        }
        restValidations.validIdentityProxy(identityProxy.getIdentityProxy(),identityProxy.getIdentityProxyType());
        if(userHelper.addUserIdentityProxy(partnerId, userId,identityProxy.getIdentityProxy(),identityProxy.getIdentityProxyType(), null, 30L,true)) {
            successResponseVO.setSuccess(RESTConstants.TRUE);
        } else {
            successResponseVO.setSuccess(RESTConstants.FALSE);
        }
    } catch (BusinessServiceException be) {
        try{
             if(be.getNewInformationCode().equalsIgnoreCase(BusinessErrorCodes.UNIQUE_PROXY_PHONE_ERROR.toString())){
                    throw new RestValidationException(RestErrorCodes.VALIDATION_UNIQUE_PHONE_PROXY.toString());}
                 else if(be.getNewInformationCode().equalsIgnoreCase(BusinessErrorCodes.UNIQUE_PROXY_EMAIL_ERROR.toString())){
                     throw new RestValidationException(RestErrorCodes.VALIDATION_UNIQUE_EMAIL_PROXY.toString());
                 }else if(be.getNewInformationCode().equalsIgnoreCase(BusinessErrorCodes.UNIQUE_PROXY_LOYALTY_ERROR.toString())){
                     throw new RestValidationException(RestErrorCodes.VALIDATION_UNIQUE_LOYALTY_PROXY.toString());
                 }else{
                     throw new BusinessServiceException(partnerId, "Error in UserRestController : updateUser()", be, be.getNewInformationCode(), params);
                 } 
            }catch(RestValidationException ve){
                throw new RestValidationException(partnerId, "Error in UserRestController : updateUser()", ve, ve.getNewInformationCode(), params);
            }

        }catch (RestValidationException ve){
            throw new RestValidationException(partnerId, "Error in UserRestController : updateUser()", ve, ve.getNewInformationCode(), params);
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RestInternalErrorException(partnerId, "Error in UserRestController : updateUser()", e, null, params);
        } 

    return successResponseVO;
}
```

EasyMock Code:

```
   @Test(expected = BusinessServiceException.class)
    public void testUpdateUserDetailBusinessServiceExceptionEmail() throws BusinessException, RestValidationException,RestInternalErrorException {

        UserDetailVO userDetailVO = new UserDetailVO();
        UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
        userDetail.setPhoneNumber("04828229279");
        userDetail.setEmail("divya@gmail.com");
        String deliveryType = "deliveryType";
        List<UserDeliveryPreference> userDeliveryPreference = new ArrayList<UserDeliveryPreference>();
        UserDeliveryPreference e = new UserDeliveryPreference();
        e.setDeliveryType(deliveryType);
        userDeliveryPreference.add(e);
        userDetail.setUserDeliveryPreference(userDeliveryPreference);
        userDetail.setSendDigitalReceipt("never");
        UserEvent userEvent = new UserEvent();
        userEvent.setEventType(EventsType.UserPreferenceUpdate.toString());
        userEvent.setPartnerId(partnerId);
        userEvent.setUserId(userId);
        userEvent.setTimestamp(new Date());
        userEvent.setChannel(Channel.rest.toString());
        EasyMock.expect(request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for")).andReturn("x-forwarded-for");
        EasyMock.expect(request.getHeader("user-agent")).andReturn("user-agent");
        Map<String, String> details = new HashMap<String, String>();
        details.put(RESTConstants.IP_ADDRESS, "x-forwarded-for");
        details.put(RESTConstants.HTTP_USER_AGENT, "user-agent");
        details.put(RESTConstants.APPID, "4567");
        userEvent.setDetails(details);
        EasyMock.expect(restValidations.validateDeliveryPreference(userDetailVO)).andReturn(true);
        EasyMock.expect(userHelper.populateuserDetail(userDetailVO)).andReturn(userDetail);
        EasyMock.expect( restValidations.isAllRequiredFieldExistsForUserUpdate(userDetail)).andReturn(true);
        EasyMock.expect(restValidations.validatePhonePattern("04828229279")) .andReturn(true);
        EasyMock.expect(restValidations.validateEmailPattern("divya@gmail.com")).andReturn(true);
        EasyMock.expect( restValidations.validDeliveryPreference(userDeliveryPreference)) .andReturn(true);
        EasyMock.expect(restValidations.validateOptin("never")).andReturn("never");
        String newInformationCode = BusinessErrorCodes.UNIQUE_PROXY_EMAIL_ERROR.toString();
        Serializable[] params = null;
        try {
            EasyMock.expect(userHelper.updateUserDetail(EasyMock.same(userId),EasyMock.same(partnerId),EasyMock.isA(UserDetail.class),EasyMock.isA(UserEvent.class))).andThrow( new BusinessServiceException(partnerId, "fails", null, newInformationCode, params));
            EasyMock.replay(userHelper, request, restValidations);
            userController.updateUser(partnerId, userId, "4567", "1.0", "nonce", userDetailVO, request);
        } finally {
            EasyMock.verify(userHelper, request, restValidations);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your update method looks a little odd. Why are you throwing a RestValidationException, catching it and then doing nothing with it?

Comment: @JamesB I imagine the OP has removed code for brevity.

Comment: @DanTemple Hope so :-)

Comment: Can you show us the entire test method please?

Comment: Hi...I have uploaded complete code..Kindly check and help.

Comment: Have you debugged the test and checked the line where it leaves the updateUser method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your test is expecting the wrong exception type to be thrown.

Change:

```
@Test(expected = BusinessServiceException.class)
public void testUpdate(parameters){
```

to:

```
@Test(expected = RestValidationException.class)
public void testUpdate(parameters){
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.What I understood is which exception we throw with addThrrow() & expect(), should specify with @Test notation. I i write @Test(expected = RestValidationException.class) Unexpected RestValidException  but got BusinessServiceException

Comment: The expected value within the Test annotation is the type of exception thrown out by the method under test - i.e. update.

Comment: Thank you..What I understood when I post this question was wrong."The expected value within the Test annotation is the type of exception thrown out by the method under test" is the correct concept. Now  my code works fine.Thanks once again.